# Como chamar o php no html e fazer a validação de um formulário?

Tags: php, html, validação

Estou validando um formulário em que o usuário irá preencher os campos :

- Nome
- Sobrenome
- Email
- Telefone
- Mensagem

Através destes, quero validar para caso o usuário não digite nestes campos apareça uma mensagem dizendo que é necessário preencher os campos.

Eu já consegui criar em `php` uma validação para estes campos, mas como sou um programador ainda novo no `php`,eu não sei se estou fazendo direito esta chamada do `php`,dentro do `html` estou usando método `post`,para pegar os campos.

**Código php :**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
$erro = 0;


//Verifica se o campo nome não está em branco.
if(empty($nome) OR strstr ($nome,'')==false)
{
    echo("Favor digitar seu nome"; $erro =1;);  
}

//Verifica se o campo sobrenome não está em branco.
if(empty($sobrenome) OR strstr ($nome,'') ==false)
{
    echo("Favor digitar seu sobrenome";$erro=1;);
}

//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
if(strlen($email)<8 || strstr($email,'@')==false)
{
    echo("Favor digitar seu email corretamente";$erro = 1;);    
}

//Verifica se o campo telefone está sendo preenchido com texto.
if(!is_numeric($telefone)) 
{
    echo("Preencha o campo telefone somente com números.";$erro = 1;);
}

//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
if(empty($mensagem) OR strstr ($mensagem,'') ==false)
{
    echo("Favor digitar sua mensagem";erro = 1;)    
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou utilizando o `form action = "validar.php"` no formulário. Na hora em que coloco para enviar o formulário, ele não aparece nada,e vai para a página do `php` em que eu criei, chamada `validar.php`.Nem sequer faz a verificação dos campos.

Como posso fazer isto funcionar ? Se alguém puder me ajudar irei ficar grato.

Comment: Quando submetes o formulário ele vai diretamente para action, e é nesse ficheiro que tens de fazer as validações

Comment: Porque não usa a tag required nos inputs do formulário?

Comment: Este código que colocou é do arquivo `validar.php`? Coloque também seu código html.

Comment: @Diego Estou usando agora a tag required nos inputs do formulário.

Comment: @Falion isso resolve seu problema né?

Comment: Não,na verdade quase,pois quero que tenha mensagens específicas para cada textbox,por exemplo o do nome : "Preencha o campo com o seu nome".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código `php` está cheio de erro de sintaxe (principalmente nos `echo`). O correto (não tão correto) seria:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
$erro = 0;


//Verifica se o campo nome não está em branco.
if(empty($nome) OR !strstr($nome,''))
{
    echo "Favor digitar seu nome";  
}

//Verifica se o campo sobrenome não está em branco.
if(empty($sobrenome) OR !strstr($nome,''))
{
    echo "Favor digitar seu sobrenome";
}

//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
if(strlen($email)<8 || !strstr($email,'@'))
{
    echo "Favor digitar seu email corretamente";    
}

//Verifica se o campo telefone está sendo preenchido com texto.
if(!is_numeric($telefone)) 
{
    echo "Preencha o campo telefone somente com números.";
}

//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
if(empty($mensagem) OR !strstr($mensagem,''))
{
    echo "Favor digitar sua mensagem";    
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Um exemplo de formulário:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>POST</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="teste.php" method="post">
        <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Seu nome..." />
        <input name="sobrenome" type="text" placeholder="Seu sobrenome..." />
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Seu email..." />
        <input name="telefone" type="tel" placeholder="Seu telefone..." />
        <textarea name="mensagem" type="text" placeholder="Sua mensagem..."> </textarea>
        <input name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Poderia usar o atributo `required` do HTML para tornar o campo obrigatório. Assim:

```
<input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Seu nome..." required />
```

Outra melhor forma seria:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>POST</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
$erro = 0;


//Verifica se o campo nome não está em branco.
echo !empty($nome) ? "Nome: {$nome}<br/>" : "Favor digitar seu nome<br/>";

//Verifica se o campo sobrenome não está em branco.
echo !empty($sobrenome) ? "Sobrenome: {$sobrenome}<br/>" : "Favor digitar seu sobrenome<br/>";

//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
echo (!empty($email) and filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? "Email: {$email}<br/>" : "Favor digitar seu email ou um email válido<br/>";

//Verifica se o campo telefone está sendo preenchido com texto.
echo (strlen($email) >= 8 and filter_var($telefone, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
    ? "Telefone: {$telefone}<br/>"
    : "Preencha o campo telefone somente com números.<br/>";


//Verifica se o campo email não está em branco.
echo !empty($mensagem) ? "Mensagem: {$mensagem}<br/>" : "Favor digitar sua mensagem<br/>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Resumidamente, o ! pega o resultado inverso, quando coloco `!empty($var)`, quero dizer quando a variável NÃO for vazia.

Mas e os `if`? Sumiram?

Sim e não, usei os operadores ternários, que podem ser explicados aqui:

[O básico - PHP do jeito certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/pages/The-Basics.html)

Para ver mais:
[PHP do jeito certo](http://br.phptherightway.com)

Comment: Olá amigo,seu código funcionou mas em certas partes não,por exemplo ele não fala para o usuário "Favor digitar seu nome" e sim "Preencha o campo",e na parte do telefone ele não verifica se o usuário digitou somente números,pois testei com texto e foi normalmente.Como posso resolver isto ?

Comment: Você usou o formulário da resposta?

Comment: Não,usei o meu mesmo.

Comment: Vi no comentário acima, se está usando o atributo `required` então é padrão que ele nao vai deixar você clicar em enviar com um campo vazio mostrando a mensagem "Preencha esse campo"

Comment: Mas se eu tirar o required do código,ele não funciona aquele seu código,por que ele não faz a validação

Comment: Aqui esta normal.. Tenta com formulário da minha resposta.

Comment: Testei com o seu código agora e ele também não faz a validação.

Comment: Aqui pegou normal, acho que você não está entendendo é o conceito do PHP e da forma como está sendo utilizado. De toda forma o formulário vai ser enviado, mesmo se o número de telefone for composto por letras. Mas no PHP vai dar um echo na tela dizendo que o telefone deve ser composto por números. Caso queira que não passe pelo formulário, use Ajax ou retorne o erro por parâmetro com o `header("Location:pagina.php?erro='O erro que deu'")`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a validação da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$input = $_POST;
$erro = false;

if (isset($input['enviar'])) {

    if (in_array("",$input)){

      $erro = 'Favor preencher todos os campos do formulário';

   } elseif (filter_var($input['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

      $erro = 'Favor informar um e-mail válido';

   } elseif(!is_numeric($input['telefone'])) {

     $erro = 'O campo telefone deve conter apenas números';
   }

   if ($erro){
     echo $erro;
   }

}

?>
```

ou caso queira passar a mensagem para cada campo

```
<?php

$input = $_POST;
$erro = [];

if (isset($input['enviar'])) {

   foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

      if ($value == ""){

        $campo = str_replace(["_","-"]," ",$key);

        $error[] = 'O campo '.$campo.' deve ser preenchido';
      }

   }

    if (empty($error) && filter_var($input['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))      {

      $erro[] = 'Favor informar um e-mail válido';

   } elseif(empty($error) && !is_numeric($input['telefone'])) {

     $erro[] = 'O campo telefone deve conter apenas números';
   }

   if ($erro){
     var_dump($erro);
   }

}

?>
```